# Why python setuptools failed to upload package to repo gives exit code of 0

Tags: python

This is the output from our Jenkins server, I get exit code 0, running Python 2.7.6:

```
python setup.py sdist upload -r jfrog
...
...
Upload failed (403): Forbidden
jenkins@jenkins:~/workspace/es_master-R6P3NSWIXXZLP7T4IE7S$ echo $?
0
```

But when I run the same thing on my computer, I get exit code 1, running Python on 2.7.10:

```
python setup.py sdist upload -r jfrog
...
...
Upload failed (403): Forbidden
Jamess-iMac-4:project jameslin$ echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across this issue raised:

[Failed upload not reflected in exit code](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/869)

Problem happens on newer version of distutils

**UPDATE**: Python 2.7.7 has fixed this issue.